# Is every inductive set also transitive?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I stumbled upon this exercise:

> Prove that, if $X$ is an inductive set, then $Y=\{x \in X\colon x \subset X\}$ is inductive.

I easily proved that $\emptyset \in Y$ but then I could not find a way to show that $\forall y \in Y, y \cup \{ y \} \in Y$.

Is every inductive set transitive? Obviously, if every inductive set were transitive, the exercise would be pretty trivial. 
Could anyone clarify this for me? I would be really grateful.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, I do actually ask the question which is in the title also in the body. The (other) question in the body is what made me think about the question in the title.

Comment: Ah, you are correct. I'm sorry for not reading better... :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\emptyset \in Y$ since $X$ is inductive.

Suppose $x \in Y$. Then by definition $x \in X$ and $x \subset X$. Since $X$ is inductive $x \cup \{x\} \in X$. $x \cup \{x\} \subset X$ since $x \subset X$ and $x \in X$. So $x \cup \{x\} \in Y$ since it has been shown that $x \cup \{x\} \in X$ and $x \cup \{x\} \subset X$.

Comment: Thank you! Now i got it and it was pretty easy.

Answer (score 1):

Look again at the definition of $Y$: $Y=\{x\in X:x\subseteq X\}$, so by definition every element of $Y$ is both a subset **and an element** of $X$. Thus, if $y\in Y$, automatically $y\in X$ and $\{y\}\subseteq X$. Since $y\in X$, $y\cup\{y\}\in X$, and clearly $y\cup\{y\}\subseteq X$, so $y\cup\{y\}\in Y$.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is any set, then you can start making an inductive set by letting
$S_0=\{A\}$ and recursively $S_{n+1} = \{ x \cup \{x\}\mid x \in S_n\} \cup S_0$.
Then $S_\omega :=\bigcup S_n$ has the successor property of an inductive set.
Finally $I:=\omega \cup S_\omega$ is inductive, that is $\emptyset \in I$ and $x\in I\Rightarrow x\cup\{x\}\in I$.

Note that $A\in I$ but not necessarily $A\subset I$, for example if the elments of $A$ are not ordinals.

Comment: Yes, now I understand! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As to your question about whether every inductive set is transitive, certainly not. Let $\mathbb{N}$ be the natural numbers as ordinarily defined. Let $a=\{\{\{\{\emptyset\}\}\}\}$, and let $A$ be the inductive closure of $\{a\}$. Let $B=\mathbb{N}\cup A$. The $B$ is inductive but not transitive.

Comment: 1. What does "inductive closure" mean? 2. Just to be clear, is the following definition correct? A set $x$ is *inductive* iff every subset of $x$ is a member of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not need to be transitive. I suspect you're overcomplicating the task; what you need follows directly from the definitions:

If $y\in Y$, then in particular $y\in X$. Because $X$ is transitive we then have $y\cup\{y\}\in X$. That is half or proving that $y\cup\{y\}$ is in $Y$. The other half requires $y\cup\{y\}\subset X$. Now remember what $y\in Y$ means...

Comment: @dado: If $A\subset X$ and $B\subset X$ then $A\cup B\subset X$. Now set $A=y$ and $B=\{y\}$. The two premises are then exactly the condition for $y\in Y$ to hold.

Comment: But I still don't see how an inductive set need not be transitive. All the examples of inductive set that I can think of are transitive (i.e. every element is also a subset of the set!).

Comment: @dado: On further thought I think there are perhaps multiple definitions of "inductive" around, where some may imply that $\omega$ is the _only_ inductive set around, and if so, every inductive set is transitive simply because $\omega$ is. However, I think the more common definition is that an inductive set is one that contains $\varnothing$ and is closed under the function $S(a)=a\cup\{a\}$. Then the set $\omega \cup \{S^n(\{\{42\}\})\mid n\in\omega\}$ is inductive but not transitive, since it contains $\{\{42\}\}$ but not $\{42\}$.

Comment: Thank you. The only inductive sets I could think of were simply $\omega$ in disguise (that's why I thought they were all transitive!).